# Change the color for a keyword in Vim for ALL filetypes

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, word-wrap

I'm using `&showbreak=repeat(' ', 5)` to add indentation to wordwrapped lines. What I WANT to do is add a bright red `>>>>` instead.

How would I change all `>>>>` occurrences in all files to red? For wordwrapping readability.

Soft wrapping of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, `:set lcs=extends:>,precedes:<` only accepts single characters.

Comment: That's ok! I just found out how to highlight lines past 80 characters via `match Typedef '\%>80v.\+'` which makes wrapped lines light up like christmas : ) Also, apparently >>>> defaults to a nice blue. I'm ok with this. Thanks though!

Edit: Still, hopefully someone can dream up an answer, since I can't be the only one ever to want to do this.